# attempting to combine two foreach loops PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have two separate sql statements and i am attempting to combine two foreach loops in order to display them.

The reasoning behind having two sql loops was because there was an interference between the 'proposal_id' field between the 'record' table and 'proposal_tag' table since both of these use 'proposal_id' to LEFT JOIN on. So i though doing two separate statements and then using the foreach to loop through them would help.

I have a table which gets populated by this line `foreach ($proposals as $proposal)` and want to do a similar thing for the tag field.

I have tried to use `foreach ($tags as $tag => $proposalInfo)` but this didn't work and it repeated the table information over and over again because there are three tags per proposal.

this is the code i have at the moment:

```
<body>

  <?php

  try {

    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, u.user_record_id, u.forename, u.surname, c.course_title FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_record_id = p.user_record_id
      LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
      LEFT JOIN record r on r.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      WHERE p.source = "Supervisor"
      AND (r.status_code not in (3,8) OR r.status_code IS NULL)
      GROUP BY p.proposal_id');
    $stmt->execute();

    $proposals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $proposalTags = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_title) AS tags FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
      GROUP BY p.proposal_id');
    $proposalTags->execute();

    $tags = $proposalTags->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
  }
  ?>
  <h4><center>View All Proposals</center></h4>

  <div class = "container container-fluid"id = "table_container" style="width:auto; margin-top:40px;" class="mainbox col-md-6">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12">


        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
          <thead>
            <tr >
              <th class="text-center">
                Proposal ID
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Proposal Title
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Proposal Description
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Course
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                Tags
              </th>
               <th class="text-center">
                Supervisor
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- populating the table with information from mysql database -->
            <?php foreach ($proposals as $proposal) {

              echo "<tr><td>";
              echo $proposal['proposal_id'];
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo substr($proposal['proposal_title'],0,30) ."...";
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo substr($proposal['description'],0,50) ."...";
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo $proposal['course_title'];
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo $tags['tags'];
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo $proposal['forename'] . ' ' . $lect['surname'];
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo '<p data-placement="top"
              data-toggle="tooltip"
              style="margin-left:5px" 
              title="Full View">';
              echo '<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" 
              data-title="View" 
              data-toggle="modal" 
              data-id="'; 
              echo $proposal['proposal_id']; 
              echo '" data-proposal="'; 
              echo $proposal['proposal_title'];
              echo '" data-desc="'; 
              echo $proposal['description'];
              echo '" data-course="'; 
              echo $proposal['course_title'];
              echo '" data-tag="'; 
              echo $proposal['tags'];
              echo '" data-target="#viewModal">';
              echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" />';
              echo '</button></p>';
              echo "</tr>"; }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

really confused on how i can show the tags.

The page looks like this:

[image: the table]

Attempt with tags added:

[image: with tag attempt]

any help would be much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0):

if `$proposal` and `$tags` have the same index you can try:

```
<?php 
   foreach ($proposals as $index => $proposal) {

             ...
              echo "</td><td>";
              echo $tags[$index]['tags'];
              echo "</td><td>";
             ... 
   }
?>
```